# Static nested floating within a page using WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress

I have made a simple example here ->http://jsfiddle.net/Tryah85/DV4N8/

```
#contactContainer {
background-color: #999;
float: left;
font-weight:900;
text-align:center;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.contactLeft {
position:relative;
margin:auto;
background-color:lime;
float: left;
margin: 0 0 0 0;
width: 230px;
border-left: thick solid #006;
padding-left: 33px;
height: 100px;
}

.contactRight {
position:relative;
margin:auto;
background-color:yellow;
text-align:right;
float: left;
width: 230px;
border-right: thick solid #006; 
padding-right: 33px;
padding-top: 10px;
height: 90px;
}
```

I am using the standard theme this year- twentyfourteen. I want two boxes to work responsively when the screen is minimized, box B falls under A like has done in the mockup fiddle I made. I have tried nesting 2 classes inside of an ID. From this example you will notice I used three IDs instead.

I embedded the CSS within the Wordpress page and it only recognizes the first Div.

Basically I am making a contact page with the left div having an address, and the right to have contact information. When a person with a smartphone/iPhone views the page the boxes are stacked- my example works, but not in Wordpress. Anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured this out. CSS can be embedded within a page (when loading static strings into the dashboard). It only works when there are no empty spaces between classes and IDs. This not important in other CSS files I have worked with, but this took me a while to figure out.

Enter like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
#contactContainer {
background-color: #999;
float: left;
font-weight:900;
text-align:center;
margin: 0 auto;
}                      <---------NO SPACE
.contactLeft {
width: 230px;
border-left: thick solid #006;
padding-left: 33px;
height: 100px;
}                         <---------NO SPACE
.contactRight {
text-align:right;
float: left;
width: 230px;
border-right: thick solid #006; 
padding-right: 33px;
padding-top: 10px;
height: 90px;
}
</style>
```